# Cost of patenting in Europe

Tags: cost

What is the total cost of patenting a medical device in Europe? Of all the costs, which ones are compulsory?

I have also heard that the cost will significantly reduce with a new system. Is that already in place? If not, will it be in place any time soon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the total cost of patenting a medical device in Europe?

Cost of Filing Patent change from time to time, at present cost of filing application can be found at following EP interactive tool:-

**[Schedule of Fees](http://www.epoline.org/portal/portal/default/epoline.Scheduleoffees)**

Then selecting the **Fee Group** based on your requirement.

For your reference filing a application and related cost on various matter will be as follows:-

[image]

Please note that these fees are official fees and does not involve attorney costs.

In normal course as fresh filing You need to provide fee for CODE 1 (only one online or physical filing), 2 and 5. if claims are more than 15 additional fee as CODE 15; If certified copy is to be provided then code 29; if page exceeds 36 CODE 501; and if divisional is filed CODE 552-555 based on applicability.

> I have also heard that the cost will significantly reduce with a new
>   system. Is that already in place? If not, will it be in place any time
>   soon?

At present No fee changes notification are given and most likely they wont change in recent time.

Comment: Hi Pushpak, thanks again! Of all these costs, which ones are "compulsory" and which ones optional?

Comment: specified as per your comment. please add them to your question.

Comment: I accepted it already. Has it not updated in your profile? Maybe it requires some time...