# Provisional Patent in Europe

Tags: patent-lifetime, provisional-application

I want to see if an idea can work in the **European** market, but I want to protect it.

Can I fill a provisional patent application in Europe, and then if the idea does not work just disregard the patent and not pay the full cost?

If that is the case, what is the cost of the provisional patent and for how long will it protect my product?

Where can I start looking at it?

Thanks!

Comment: since you are inventor looking for more info on US EP i request you to look for WIPO application it will cost you less and you have approximately 2 years to go in US EP if invention worth. OR even better you can license for world wide without paying US EP money.

Comment: Thanks, what is US EP?

Comment: US united states EP European

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can file patent application online using EPO online. however they are require you to provide complete application.

**what is the cost of the provisional patent application?**

already answered:- [Cost of patenting in Europe](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/12162/11895)

If patent application has 15 claims and 35 pages then official cost for natural person will be approximately 600 EUR. see [Article 78](http://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/epc/2013/e/ar78.html), [Rule 17](http://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/epc/2013/e/r17.html) and [Article 14(4)](http://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/epc/2013/e/ar14.html). Time limit for providing fee is one month.

**How long it will protect my product?**

If granted patent will protect your product for 20 years from date of filing.

**Where to look?**

[Guide for applicants, Part 1](http://www.epo.org/applying/european/Guide-for-applicants.html): How to get a European patent

**Requirement of Attorney?**

If you have your residence or principal place of business in a contracting state, you may act on your own behalf in proceedings before the EPO

If you have neither a residence nor your principal place of business in a contracting state, you must appoint a representative and act through him in all proceedings before the EPO other than in filing your European patent application and paying the fees.

Comment: Pushpak thanks again. The thing is that I would like to know the specific price for the provisional patent and how long does it last in Europe (only the provisional)

Comment: I have tried to include basic cost it may be accurate

Comment: And for how long does the provisional patrbt protect in Europe?

Comment: Epo requires complete filing. Specification with claims. Provisonal protection as stated with EPC is valid if application is alive